# How to disable HP LaserJet Pro 400 M401dne from going into standby mode after inactivity?

Tags: windows-7, printing, printer, hp-laserjet

We've had this HP LaserJet Pro 400 M401dne printer in our office for about a year now and it's been working really fast. For some stupid reason I decided to check for an update on the HP site and downloaded and installed a driver & firmware update. Now the printer doesn't work as it used to. The most annoying thing is that now after some time of inactivity it enters some sort of a standby mode and it takes up to several seconds for it to come out of it when we print something. (I need to point out that this printer is used in our office on a regular basis.)

So my question is how to disable this standby mode?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the printer can be disabled or adjusted through the steps below depending on the version of your printer:

```
http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c03304145&sp4ts.oid=5096252
```

I hope that helps

Comment: Thanks. Although it didn't work. It's ridiculous, the `Sleep/Auto Off After` has only options of up to 1 hour but no "never" setting.